# Jest snapshot failing: val.getMockName is not a function

Tags: mocking, tdd, jestjs, snapshot, automocking

I'm trying to set up a snapshot for a small react component but I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: val.getMockName is not a function

it('renders correctly', () => {
const wrapper = renderer.create(<Partners content={content} />).toJSON()
> 
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
               ^
})
```

This is my test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Partners from './index'
import { content } from '../../content/anywhere-everywhere'

jest.mock('react-lazy-load', () => 'LazyLoad')

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = renderer.create(<Partners content={content} />).toJSON()
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This is the component

```
import React from 'react'
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load'

const Partners = ({ content }) => (
  <section className="partners">
    <h3>{content.partnersCopy}</h3>
    <div className="partners__slider">
      {content.partnerLogos.map((partnerLogo, index) => (
        <LazyLoad key={index}>
          <img src={partnerLogo.src} alt={partnerLogo.alt} />
        </LazyLoad>
      ))}
    </div>
  </section>
)

export default Partners
```

and i set up a **mocks** folder

```
'use strict'

const LazyLoad = jest.genMockFromModule('react-lazy-load')

export default LazyLoad
```

Answer (score 4):

Just resolve the image source with a **string**, it will resolve your issue.

Example: In **package.json**, I changed from

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
"^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
 }
```

to

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
"^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": ""<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
        }
    }
```

and created a file in **__mocks__/fileMock.js** in root directory with a content

```
module.exports  =  'test-file-stub'
```

[you can check here for more details](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4991)

Comment: I have the same issue but it seems not working for me!

Comment: Try to use `wrapper.element`. For example:`expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()`.